# How to Filter Loop In Genesis Studiopress AgentPress Listings Plugin?

Tags: filter, genesis

I need help creating a filter to change "View Listings" on Line 84 of code below to "Book Now".

I need help making a custom filter for the child theme functions.php file so it doesn't keep changing back when the plugin is updated. you can see the site here: https://webclient.co/running - The loop is on the home page for the running tours.

```
<?php
    class AgentPress_Featured_Listings_Widget extends WP_Widget {

        function __construct() {
            $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'featured-listings', 'description' => __( 'Display grid-style featured listings', 'agentpress-listings' ) );
            $control_ops = array( 'width' => 300, 'height' => 350 );
            parent::__construct( 'featured-listings', __( 'AgentPress - Featured Listings', 'agentpress-listings' ), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
        }

        function widget( $args, $instance ) {

            /** defaults */
            $instance = wp_parse_args( $instance, array(
                'title'          => '',
                'posts_per_page' => 10
            ) );

            extract( $args );

            echo $before_widget;

                if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
                    echo $before_title . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base ) . $after_title;
                }

                $toggle = ''; /** for left/right class */

                $query_args = array(
                    'post_type'      => 'listing',
                    'posts_per_page' => $instance['posts_per_page'],
                    'paged'          => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1
                );

                query_posts( $query_args );
                if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    //* initialze the $loop variable
                    $loop        = '';

                    //* Pull all the listing information
                    $custom_text = genesis_get_custom_field( '_listing_text' );
                    $price       = genesis_get_custom_field( '_listing_price' );
                    $address     = genesis_get_custom_field( '_listing_address' );
                    $city        = genesis_get_custom_field( '_listing_city' );
                    $state       = genesis_get_custom_field( '_listing_state' );
                    $zip         = genesis_get_custom_field( '_listing_zip' );

                    $loop .= sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', get_permalink(), genesis_get_image( array( 'size' => 'properties' ) ) );

                    if ( $price ) {
                        $loop .= sprintf( '<span class="listing-price">%s</span>', $price );
                    }

                    if ( strlen( $custom_text ) ) {
                        $loop .= sprintf( '<span class="listing-text">%s</span>', esc_html( $custom_text ) );
                    }

                    if ( $address ) {
                        $loop .= sprintf( '<span class="listing-address">%s</span>', $address );
                    }

                    if ( $city || $state || $zip ) {

                        //* count number of completed fields
                        $pass = count( array_filter( array( $city, $state, $zip ) ) );

                        //* If only 1 field filled out, no comma
                        if ( 1 == $pass ) {
                            $city_state_zip = $city . $state . $zip;
                        }
                        //* If city filled out, comma after city
                        elseif ( $city ) {
                            $city_state_zip = $city . ", " . $state . " " . $zip;
                        }
                        //* Otherwise, comma after state
                        else {
                            $city_state_zip = $city . " " . $state . ", " . $zip;
                        }

                        $loop .= sprintf( '<span class="listing-city-state-zip">%s</span>', trim( $city_state_zip ) );

                    }

                    $loop .= sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="more-link">%s</a>', get_permalink(), __( 'View Listings', 'agentpress-listings' ) );

                    $toggle = $toggle == 'left' ? 'right' : 'left';

                    /** wrap in post class div, and output **/
                    printf( '<div class="%s"><div class="widget-wrap"><div class="listing-wrap">%s</div></div></div>', join( ' ', get_post_class( $toggle ) ), apply_filters( 'agentpress_featured_listings_widget_loop', $loop ) );

                endwhile; endif;
                wp_reset_query();

            echo $after_widget;

        }

        function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
            return $new_instance;
        }

        function form( $instance ) {

            $instance = wp_parse_args( $instance, array(
                'title'          => '',
                'posts_per_page' => 10
            ) );

            printf( '<p><label for="%s">%s</label><input type="text" id="%s" name="%s" value="%s" style="%s" /></p>', $this->get_field_id('title'), __( 'Title:', 'agentpress-listings' ), $this->get_field_id('title'), $this->get_field_name('title'), esc_attr( $instance['title'] ), 'width: 95%;' );

            printf( '<p>%s <input type="text" name="%s" value="%s" size="3" /></p>', __( 'How many results should be returned?', 'agentpress-listings' ), $this->get_field_name('posts_per_page'), esc_attr( $instance['posts_per_page'] ) );

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin has the filter 'agentpress_featured_listings_widget_loop', so this should do it. It goes in your functions.php file or your functions plugin.

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/

Reference: http://www.studiopress.com/forums/topic/agent-press-listing/#post-122180

```
/**
 * Filter the loop output of the AgentPress Featured Listings Widget.
 */
function agentpress_featured_listings_widget_loop_filter( $loop ) {

    $loop = ''; /** initialze the $loop variable */

    $loop .= sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', get_permalink(), genesis_get_image( array( 'size' => 'properties' ) ) );

    $loop .= sprintf( '<span class="entry-title">' . ( get_the_title() ) . '</span>' );

    $loop .= sprintf( '<span class="listing-price">%s</span>', genesis_get_custom_field('_listing_price') );

    $custom_text = genesis_get_custom_field( '_listing_text' );
    if( strlen( $custom_text ) )
        $loop .= sprintf( '<span class="listing-text">%s</span>', esc_html( $custom_text ) );

    $loop .= sprintf( '<span class="listing-address">%s</span>', genesis_get_custom_field('_listing_address') );

    $loop .= sprintf( '<span class="listing-city-state-zip">%s %s, %s</span>', genesis_get_custom_field('_listing_city'), genesis_get_custom_field('_listing_state'), genesis_get_custom_field('_listing_zip') );

    // Here is where you change the text:
    $loop .= sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="more-link">%s</a>', get_permalink(), __( 'Book Now', 'yourtextdomain' ) );

    return $loop;

}
add_filter( 'agentpress_featured_listings_widget_loop', 'agentpress_featured_listings_widget_loop_filter', 10, 1 );
```